# Django RadioButtons with icons and not label?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have an app that have 2 fields: company_name and logo, i'm displaying the companies like radiobutton in my Form from Model, but i want to show the logo company instead of the company label (company name)

Any idea ?

My forms:

```
class RecargaForm(ModelForm):
    compania = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Compania.objects.all(), initial=0 ,empty_label='None', widget=forms.RadioSelect()) 

    class Meta:
        model = Recarga
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something similar to the technique I propose in the answer to this (my own) question: [How do I create a Django form that displays a checkbox label to the right of the checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572263/how-do-i-create-a-django-form-that-displays-a-checkbox-label-to-the-right-of-the)

Instead of writing a filter that flips the markup around, you'll need to somehow get the filter to replace the labels with the appropriate images.

Admittedly, this sounds kinda awkward to work with.