# Django BooleanField does not display label

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am fiddling around with Django forms and Django Crispy Forms (using Bootstrap as my theme).  I defined two fields:

```
test1 = forms.BooleanField(label='Some label here', help_text='help text here')
```

and

```
test2 = forms.CharField(label='another label', help_text='more help text')
```

When I render my form, the test2 field shows the label like:

```
another label: <input box>
```

with 'more help text' underneath.

However, for the test1 (BooleanField), the label seems to change the value displayed after the text box, i.e.

```
[] 'Some label here'
help text here
```

Is there a way to make it display more like:

```
Some label here []
help text here
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2045308/1628832

Comment: I looked at that example, but I'm not sure how to make it work with Crispy Forms, because my template only contains the following:  {% block content %}
   {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom template for certain fields, such as:

```
Field('my_field', template='my_field_template.html')
```

In my_field_template.html, I was able to specify the order I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use can create the other way

```
my_field= forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('A','A'),),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).