# Show BooleanField checkbox before label

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm in the process of trying to minimize the amount of code I need to use to render a form with bootstrap styling with the hope of rendering with just `{{ form }}` but I haven't yet managed to find a way to render a `BooleanField` with the checkbox before the text.

```
from django.forms import Form, BooleanField
class MyForm(Form):
     field = BooleanField(label='Test Label')
MyForm().as_table()
```

The above test code will output

```html
<tr><th><label for="id_field">Test Label:</label></th><td><input class="" id="id_field" name="field" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
```

But what I'm hoping to achieve is the same look and feel as shown in the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example).

```html
<label for="id_field"><input class="" id="id_field" name="field" type="checkbox" />Test Label:</label>
```

The problem in doing this is that the rendering is handled via the form, where the [label and the field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L259) are positioned/rendered separately, and I have yet to find a place to override that will allow me to render the widget inside of the label...

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I don't want to use django-bootstrap3 etc, and I've looked through the source code for them too and cant see anywhere where they've managed to achieve this either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Django form that displays a checkbox label to the right of the checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572263/how-do-i-create-a-django-form-that-displays-a-checkbox-label-to-the-right-of-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is much more intrinsic to do than it would appear to be and involves providing a form field mixin as well as a custom widget.

All too much work for me to maintain.

However!

[`django-angular`](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) has managed to achieve this with their own [`CheckboxInput`](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/blob/master/djng/styling/bootstrap3/widgets.py#L30) and associated [`BooleanFieldMixin`](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/blob/58cb106bbfc8f8165a4f5ab2779fa4a56142bdb0/djng/styling/bootstrap3/field_mixins.py#L8), since this is something I am planning on using, it has resolved my issue.