# django - change the structure of forms so that inputs be out of labels

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

How can we change the structure of forms so that inputs be out of labels
when my form render will be displayed like this:

```
<p>
<label for="id_form-0-food_name_0"><input checked="checked" id="id_form-0-food_name_0" name="form-0-food_name" value="" type="radio"> (Nothing)</label>
<label for="id_form-0-food_name_1"><input id="id_form-0-food_name_1" name="form-0-food_name" value="1" type="radio"> خوراک مرغ</label>
<label for="id_form-0-food_name_2"><input id="id_form-0-food_name_2" name="form-0-food_name" value="2" type="radio"> خوراک لوبیا</label>
<label for="id_form-0-food_name_3"><input id="id_form-0-food_name_3" name="form-0-food_name" value="3" type="radio"> فسنجون</label>
</p>
```

but i need `input`s render out of the `label`s tag. like this:

```
<p>
<input checked="checked" id="id_form-0-food_name_0" name="form-0-food_name" value="" type="radio"><label for="id_form-0-food_name_0"> (Nothing)</label>
<input id="id_form-0-food_name_1" name="form-0-food_name" value="1" type="radio"><label for="id_form-0-food_name_1"> خوراک مرغ</label>
<input id="id_form-0-food_name_2" name="form-0-food_name" value="2" type="radio"><label for="id_form-0-food_name_2"> خوراک لوبیا</label>
<input id="id_form-0-food_name_3" name="form-0-food_name" value="3" type="radio"><label for="id_form-0-food_name_3"> فسنجون</label>
</p>
```

my `forms.py:`

```
class Reserve(ModelForm):
    food_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Food.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=RadioFieldWithoutULRenderer), 
        empty_label="(Nothing)",
        # label=''
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('food_name',)
```

and `form.html`

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for form in formset %}

<p>
  <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" value="" />
  {{ form.food_name  }}
</p>

{% endfor %}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Related: [Show BooleanField checkbox before label](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34747964/1324033) - Believe me, its incredibly difficult to get any control over which side the label appears. Either keep it as it is or use something like django-angular that has done the hard work

Answer (score 0):

[As shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44675550) you can create your own widget using a custom template:

1. Create a template file in your templates folder (e. g. *my_project/my_app/templates/my_app/widgets/radio_option.html*):

```
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}{% if widget.wrap_label %}<label{% if widget.attrs.id %} for="{{ widget.attrs.id }}"{% endif %}>{{ widget.label }}</label>{% endif %}
```

(This template is copied and slightly modified from *django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input_option.html* which is used for radio widgets by default.)

2. Create a custom widget in your app:

```
class MyRadioSelect(django.forms.RadioSelect):
    option_template_name = "my_app/widgets/radio_option.html"
```

3. Use `MyRadioSelect` instead of `RadioSelect`