# How to do a form with a list of check items in Django, with the check box on the left?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am converting a simple checkbox list to a Django form.

Here is a the checkbox survey:

```
<input type="checkbox"><label>I like bourbon.</label><br>
<input type="checkbox"><label>I like whisky.</label><br>
<input type="checkbox"><label>I like beer.</label><br>
```

[image: html check box survey form]

Of course George Thorogood would chose all three. My grandma would chose none of them. Django doesn't have a checkbox field, and I read that I should use a BooleanField.  This is the form code:

```
 class Form_BoissonSurvey(forms.Form):
  c0 = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='I like bourbon.');
  c1 = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='I like whisky.');
  c2 = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='I like beer.');
```

And rendered it in a template.html form as:

```
  {{ form_boisson_survey.as_p }}
```

But it looks like this:

[image: attempt at a Django checkbox survey form]

I have spent beaucoup time trying to get the check boxes to the left side, and to get it to separate without the big spaces inbetween.

How can I get the check boxes on the left and get the lines to be separated by br instead of p ??  I.e. to get this to look like a normal list of three things of which any number of them may be selected?

Hmm, looks like I might need to validated that at least one is checked.

Django check lists, but check boxes need to be on the left:

[image]

[image]

Comment: please understand that django forms just translates your class into html, custom styling etc has to be done by yourself via css.  first remove `as_p` if you dont want `paragraph` tags. try `{{ form_boisson_survey.c0 }} I like bourbon.<br>` and then next line same thing with `c1...`

Comment: I am not requesting custom styling.  The html example shown above is rendered with no css.  I am just trying to get the normal behavior for a check list.  Like who would put the boxes randomly after the end of the label in a check list?  Everyone in this world puts check boxes on the left.   .. some of the check box labels in the actual application are multi line long, check boxes as though punctuation at the end of the sentence is truly confusing.

Comment: create a ticket on the django website tell them they are doing it all wrong(/s). here some people solved your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572263/how-do-i-create-a-django-form-that-displays-a-checkbox-label-to-the-right-of-the its basically what I said in my comment before but they replaced "I like bourbon." with `{{form_boisson_survey.c0.label}}`. Hope that helps

Comment: When there are only a couple of check box items in the list, and there are only a couple of lists, and the option data is not dynamic, it is practical to deconstruct the form objects by specifying fields like that with typed one time text on the template. This is not practical in general.  It is also a PIA when editing the forms to then have to go modify the templates.

Comment: yes I see it would be nice to have it all as `{{form}}` but when you are not satisfied with the result you have to modify it. writing each field as a seperate line isnt optimal, thats why for loops are great for that kinda stuff. option b would be to use css styling (like I said before)  for example `input[type="radio"] {
  float:left
}`. For further questions please read the other question I linked in the comment before.

Comment: What about [Django Crispy Forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#)? It's been a while since I used it without tweaking, but I think it renders checkboxes on the left by default.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give Crispy Forms a try.

Comment: God bless you Rob, that fixes the forms.